# Which of the sentences is grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar

Which of the sentences is grammatically correct?

> 1. The using of the opportunities offered by ... became an important element.
> 2. A significant element became the using of the opportunities offered by ...

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: "The use of opportunities"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both are grammatical, but neither is very satisfactory.

- In the first place, the ponderous construction *the VERBing of* is almost always a bad choice. If you want the *-ing* form in situations like this, employ it as a frank verb: write *using X*. If for some reason you want to bleach out any hint of ‘verbiness’, employ the ordinary noun form, *use of*.

  (*Usage* is something else again: it designates habitual or customary use, and today usually refers to use of some linguistic form.)

  Other things being equal, I recommend the verbal use; too many nouns makes your diction sound pompous and  self-important.
- In the second place, you should not speak of *using* an *opportunity*. *Use* is employed with a tool or means by which you do something.

  - Using the resources offered by ...
  - Using the software provided by ...
  - Use of equipment obtained from ...

  But an *opportunity* is not a tool or means for doing something; it is an occasion for doing something. *Opportunity* signifies a time or a situation or a state of affairs particularly suited to doing whatever it is you want to do. You would do better to use *take advantage of* or *seize* or *exploit*:

  - Taking advantage of the opportunity offered by ...
  - Seizing the opportunity afforded by ...
  - Exploiting the opportunity arising from ...

Answer (score 0):

You should use *use* or *usage* instead of *using*, because *using* is a verb form, not a noun.

> The use/usage of the opportunities offered by ... became an important element.
>
> A significant element became the use/usage of the opportunities offered by ...

Otherwise I think the meanings are similar (without further context).

Answer (score 0):

What follows complements @StoneyB 's little nugget of writer's wisdom by answering which choice of sentence is more natural.

Although both sentences are grammatical, English favours the order [subject-verb-object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject%E2%80%93verb%E2%80%93object):

> Taking advantage of the opportunity offered by ...  became an important factor

However, the order object-verb-subject can also be found specially in certain literary styles such as poetry:

> An important factor became taking advantage of the opportunity offered by ...